# Running independent loops with MapReduce

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am working on collaborative filtering project, for which I need to use an algorithm which is roughly like this:

```
itemset = set {item_1, item_2, item_3... item_n}

for (item_1 to item_n)                  // for each item in itemset
{
    for (item_2 to item_n)              // consider item_1's iteration
    {
        x = similarity (item_1, item_2) // calculate similarity of item_1 with item_2
        store x in a file
    }
}
```

This code will run in `O(n^2)` time if run serially.
`similarity` is a function which returns the similarity between `item_x` and `item_y`.

I know I can run this code in mapreduce paradigm since the each item's  ***outer*** ***loop*** iteration is independent for all items in the itemset and similarity of 1 item with other items can be computed in `O(n)` time by each mapper.

However I am a little unsure of how to go about the implementation. The item set and the features of those items are in a large single file. My confusion starts there.

do I make each mapper store the item-feature matrix in its own memory? and then each mapper calculates one item's similarity with the rest? how should I do the implementation?

I will be using Hadoop-streaming to read in the file I believe. But then how do I store other items and its features in each mapper? Can I use regular data structures to store items and its features? but each mapper won't get every other item as its input, which is my confusion.

Any help in the form of ideas,suggestion or links to articles describing how to do this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hadoop-steaming reads text over standard-in and writes to standard-out. So unless the items are strings, you might have a difficult time using Hadoop-steaming with this

Comment: @cricket_007 : i understand that ...my items are stored in one file as one string per line, all i need to know is how each mapper can be made to look at all strings.

Comment: Well, in python it would be something like `for line in sys.stdin`